# Удаление по долгому нажатию на элемент listView

Tags: java, android

Имею класс:

```
public class dialogs extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
  ...
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать удаление элемента из списка listView по долгому нажатию на него. Дл этого насколько я понял нужно добавить в определение класса строку implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
В итоге получается так:

```
public class dialogs extends Activity implements TextWatcher implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{
  ...
}
```

Но почти после этого весь класс пестрит ошибками. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Кстати, классы в яве именуются с большой буквы.

Comment: Имплементируемые интерфейсы перечисляются через запятую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сказали компилятору, что ваш класс реализует интерейс но не дали ему реализацию. Вам надо либо реализовать интерфейс в классе или сделать класс абстрактным.

Для первого варианта - просто нажмите `Alt+Enter` на имени интерфейса и выберите `implement methods` - нужный метод с пустой реализацией появится в вашем классе.